# AWK - reorder lines and separate them into blocks

Tags: algorithm, unix, awk

I have a file with thousands of lines with this aspect, which divides the blocks is the word "nominative" in the field 6. Each block, have to be divided into two sub-blocks, one with the words of the field one, that doesn't contain the letter " j "(eg: magasabbikaiké) and the other block with the words which contain the letter" j "(eg: magasabbikjaiké)

```
magasabbikaiké  /j/aiké plural  3pl singular    nominative
magasabbikjaiké /j/aiké plural  3pl singular    nominative
magasabbikaikét /j/aikét    plural  3pl singular    accusative
magasabbikjaikét    /j/aikét    plural  3pl singular    accusative
magasabbikaikénak   /j/aikénak  plural  3pl singular    dative
magasabbikjaikénak  /j/aikénak  plural  3pl singular    dative
magasabbikaikéval   /j/aikéval  plural  3pl singular    instrumental
magasabbikjaikéval  /j/aikéval  plural  3pl singular    instrumental
magasabbikaikéért   /j/aikéért  plural  3pl singular    causal-final
magasabbikjaikéért  /j/aikéért  plural  3pl singular    causal-final
magasabbikaikévá    /j/aikévá   plural  3pl singular    translative
magasabbikjaikévá   /j/aikévá   plural  3pl singular    translative
magasabbikaikéig    /j/aikéig   plural  3pl singular    terminative
magasabbikjaikéig   /j/aikéig   plural  3pl singular    terminative
magasabbikaikéban   /j/aikéban  plural  3pl singular    inessive
magasabbikjaikéban  /j/aikéban  plural  3pl singular    inessive
magasabbikaikén /j/aikén    plural  3pl singular    superessive
magasabbikjaikén    /j/aikén    plural  3pl singular    superessive
magasabbikaikénál   /j/aikénál  plural  3pl singular    adessive
magasabbikjaikénál  /j/aikénál  plural  3pl singular    adessive
magasabbikaikéba    /j/aikéba   plural  3pl singular    illative
magasabbikjaikéba   /j/aikéba   plural  3pl singular    illative
magasabbikaikéra    /j/aikéra   plural  3pl singular    sublative
magasabbikjaikéra   /j/aikéra   plural  3pl singular    sublative
magasabbikaikéhoz   /j/aikéhoz  plural  3pl singular    allative
magasabbikjaikéhoz  /j/aikéhoz  plural  3pl singular    allative
magasabbikaikéból   /j/aikéból  plural  3pl singular    elative
magasabbikjaikéból  /j/aikéból  plural  3pl singular    elative
magasabbikaikéról   /j/aikéról  plural  3pl singular    delative
magasabbikjaikéról  /j/aikéról  plural  3pl singular    delative
magasabbikaikétól   /j/aikétól  plural  3pl singular    ablative
magasabbikjaikétól  /j/aikétól  plural  3pl singular    ablative
magasabbikaikéi /j/aikéi    plural  3pl plural  nominative
magasabbikjaikéi    /j/aikéi    plural  3pl plural  nominative
magasabbikaikéit    /j/aikéit   plural  3pl plural  accusative
magasabbikjaikéit   /j/aikéit   plural  3pl plural  accusative
....
```

Desired Output:

```
magasabbikaiké  /j/aiké plural  3pl singular    nominative
magasabbikaikét /j/aikét    plural  3pl singular    accusative
magasabbikaikénak   /j/aikénak  plural  3pl singular    dative
magasabbikaikéval   /j/aikéval  plural  3pl singular    instrumental
magasabbikaikéért   /j/aikéért  plural  3pl singular    causal-final
magasabbikaikévá    /j/aikévá   plural  3pl singular    translative
magasabbikaikéig    /j/aikéig   plural  3pl singular    terminative
magasabbikaikéban   /j/aikéban  plural  3pl singular    inessive
magasabbikaikén /j/aikén    plural  3pl singular    superessive
magasabbikaikénál   /j/aikénál  plural  3pl singular    adessive
magasabbikaikéba    /j/aikéba   plural  3pl singular    illative
magasabbikaikéra    /j/aikéra   plural  3pl singular    sublative
magasabbikaikéhoz   /j/aikéhoz  plural  3pl singular    allative
magasabbikaikéból   /j/aikéból  plural  3pl singular    elative
magasabbikaikéról   /j/aikéról  plural  3pl singular    delative
magasabbikaikétól   /j/aikétól  plural  3pl singular    ablative

magasabbikjaiké /j/aiké plural  3pl singular    nominative
magasabbikjaikét    /j/aikét    plural  3pl singular    accusative
magasabbikjaikénak  /j/aikénak  plural  3pl singular    dative
magasabbikjaikéval  /j/aikéval  plural  3pl singular    instrumental
magasabbikjaikéért  /j/aikéért  plural  3pl singular    causal-final
magasabbikjaikévá   /j/aikévá   plural  3pl singular    translative
magasabbikjaikéig   /j/aikéig   plural  3pl singular    terminative
magasabbikjaikéban  /j/aikéban  plural  3pl singular    inessive
magasabbikjaikén    /j/aikén    plural  3pl singular    superessive
magasabbikjaikénál  /j/aikénál  plural  3pl singular    adessive
magasabbikjaikéba   /j/aikéba   plural  3pl singular    illative
magasabbikjaikéra   /j/aikéra   plural  3pl singular    sublative
magasabbikjaikéhoz  /j/aikéhoz  plural  3pl singular    allative
magasabbikjaikéból  /j/aikéból  plural  3pl singular    elative
magasabbikjaikéról  /j/aikéról  plural  3pl singular    delative
magasabbikjaikétól  /j/aikétól  plural  3pl singular    ablative

magasabbikaikéi /j/aikéi    plural  3pl plural  nominative
magasabbikaikéit    /j/aikéit   plural  3pl plural  accusative
....

magasabbikjaikéi    /j/aikéi    plural  3pl plural  nominative
magasabbikjaikéit   /j/aikéit   plural  3pl plural  accusative
....
```

What I have done:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t";
}
{
    id="nominative"
    if ($6 != id)
    {
        split(line_3,A,"\n")

        if (match($1,"j")==0)
        {
            line_1=line_1 $0"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            line_2=line_2 $0"\n";
        }
        line_3="";
    }
    else
    {
        line_3=line_3 $0"\n";
        print A[1]"\n"line_1;
        print A[2]"\n"line_2;

        line_1="";
        line_2="";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve, but I think you want this:

- Your file has blocks. The blocks start with lines marked "nominative", but there may be several consecutive "nominative" entries, which belong to the same block. Each block also contains other entries with other cases.
- Inside each block are words with j and words without j. You want to create two sub-blocks for each block for each class of words.
- You want to print out the sub-blocks wseparated by spaces. The data isn't changed, just rearranged.

I think you can print the entries without j straight away and save the entries with a j in a temporary string. Keep track of whether the current line and the previous line are nominative. If the current line is nominative and the previous line wasn't, flush and reset the temporary string.

The line before the first is set artificially to non-nominative. You must also flush the temporary string at the end.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";
    id = "nominative";

    prev = 0;                       # was last line "nominative"?
    withj = "";                     # temporary string for words with j
}

{
    curr = ($6 == id)               # is this line "nominative"?

    if (curr && !prev) {            # begin a new block
        print "";

        if (withj) {
            print withj;
            print "";
        }

        withj = "";
    } 

    if (match($1, "j")) {           # separate j and non-j
        withj = withj $0 "\n";
    } else {
        print;
    }

    prev = curr;
}

END {
    print "";                       # flush everything at the end
    print withj;
    print "";
}
```